# Fiware Orion Context Broker: Restrictions on subscriptions

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Does Orion support restrictions on subscriptions? Ex. I want to receive context updates only when temperature > 30

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I've tried an older version of Orion back in March. I don't know if the feature has been implemented (it's in the API).

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not implemented in NGSIv1, but planned for NGSIv2 (see `conditions` field in "Subscriptions" at [the NGSIv2 draft specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/)). However, it has not been yet implemented in the last Orion version at the time of writting this (0.25.0).

**EDIT**: this functionality has been finally implemented in Orion 0.27.0, eg:

```
POST /v2/subscriptions
...

{
    "subject": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "idPattern": ".*",
                "type": "device"
            }
        ],
        "condition": {
            "attributes": [ "temperature" ],
            "expression": {
               "q": "temperature>30"
            }
         }
    },
    "notification": {
        "callback": "http://foo.bar:5050/notify",
        "attributes": [ ]
    },
    "expires": "2050-04-05T14:00:00.00Z"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a roadmap for the functionality? When do you plan to implement it?

Comment: Orion Context Broker is developed in Agile way. Thus, we don't use long-term roadmaps, but sprint-by-sprint planning. However, you can "monitor" the progress using the following links: 1) general dashboard regarding NGSIv2 implementation (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=50130961, "Status" column), 2) backlog item for NGSIv2 subscriptions at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1316

Comment: Finally, notification filtering functionality will be available for Orion 0.27.0 release (to be released at the end of January 2016). Answer has been edited to included that information.